# Post file from one remote server to another

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Google Chrome extension. I have URL of a binary file on a remote server. I want to post that file to other server. So related function should look like this.

```
function postFileToExampleCom(fileUrl) {
    var file = ???; // Blob with data from file located at fileUrl

    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', file);

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', 'http://example.com/post/', true);
    request.send(form);
}
```

FormData.append() expects second argument to be a Blob object containing file data. What is the best way to get it? File is likely to be an image that is already loaded in active tab so it's preferable to use cache and not to download this file again.

UPD: I've tried downloading file with another XMLHttpRequest setting `responseType = 'blob'` but strangely it returns empty `response`.

Answer (score 0):

".. File is likely to be an image that is already loaded in active tab so it's preferable to use cache and not to download this file again."

1. If you saved the file locally (e.g. using localStorage or fileAPI) - then you should make sure you reading it and getting a file back and not a serialized version of the data.
2. I would debug the line of 'var file=???' and see what is the obj that you getting there.
3. It's good practice to have these 3 functions for your 'request':
   onload, onerror and onprogress.

I hope it helps.